# Questions about plotting a two-factor anova

Tags: anova, data-visualization, tukey-hsd-test

I have an experiment where I collected 36 water samples in three different streams (12 samples per stream). Subsequently, I divided these samples into 4 groups (3 samples per group), and treated them with different chemicals. Now I'm trying to understand the effect of streams and chemicals on the final quality of samples. I wrote the following code in R:

```r
    anova <- aov(samples ~ stream*chemical)
```

As a result, I obtained a significant result for the stream effect (p < 0.001), but not significant for the chemical (p=0.253) and for the stream and chemical interaction (p=0.122).
However, when I apply Tukey's test to my data, I see that there are some significant differences between sample pairs. Eg sample from stream 1 treated with chemical 1 is significantly different from sample from stream 1 treated with chemical 2.

My doubt is:
When plotting the results (I'm thinking of a bar graph), should I indicate the difference between these pairs (even if there wasn't a significant overall effect of the chemicals)?

Comment: please include a plot of your data with your response on the y axis, chemical on the x axis and a seperate line for each stream